# Odd behaviour regarding the order of putExtra methods in Android

Tags: java, android

my app asks for user input string and color and displays it on a new activity.
When transferring a string and an integer from one activity to another I found that if the putExtra for the int was below the putExtra for the string, then no string would be displayed, but if the int was on top then the string would be displayed in the specific color.

here is the broken code:

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();        
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,colorChoice);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and here is the working code

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,colorChoice);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I tried switching the getExtras' in the other_activity.java but it made no difference. Is this caused by bad coding? or its just a quirk of the language, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same key for both the items. Use a different key for `colorChoice` and `message` to get the right values.

Have static constants in either of your Activities:

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extra_message";
public static final String EXTRA_COLOR_CHOICE = "extra_color_choice";
```

Then, use them to put values:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();        
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COLOR_CHOICE, colorChoice);
startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve, you can read the values using the same `EXTRA_MESSAGE` and `EXTRA_COLOR_CHOICE` keys.

Answer (score 1):

You must call different name of `putExtra` key .

> Intent putExtra (String name,  Bundle value)

- **1st Parameter must be Unique .**

So, Create another **KEY** `EXTRA_COLOR_CHOICE` for **colorChoice**

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COLOR_CHOICE,colorChoice);
```